# Converting a NSString to an Int - Game Center

Tags: iphone, nsstring, int, game-center, gamekit

i am developing an app that uses game center but i am having a problem. I would like the player to submit their score to a leader board so they can challenge friends. Here is the code for the NSString score.

```
-(IBAction)gasPedalPressed:(id)sender {

double noSeconds = (double) [self.startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000;


NSString *reactionTime= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Good Job! You're reaction time is %1.0f Ms. Let's see if you can do better...", noSeconds];

NSString *time= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%1.0f Ms", noSeconds];


if(greenLightOn == 0)
    reactionTime = @"Slow down! You have to wait for the green light. Let's see if you can do better...";

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reaction Time" message:reactionTime 
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

and this is what i want that to comply with:

```
-(IBAction)submitscore:(id)sender {
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"1234567890"];

scoreReporter.value = score.text;    
[scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {



    if (error !=nil) {;
        NSLog(@"failed sub score");
    } else {

        NSLog(@"submitted score");

    }
}


 ];
```

}

Please Help!!

Comment: Doesn't `-[NSString intValue]` work for you?

Comment: @Costique i added this NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"time"];
    scoreInt = [myString intValue]; but it still wont work

Answer (score 2):

If you have the string:

```
NSSting *myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"2"];
```

You can get an int value from the string with:

```
int i = [myString intValue];
```

---

[edit] - In response to your comment:

Since you already create noSeconds as a double, there isn't really a need to cast it to an NSString then back.  You can simply pass noSeconds to the GKScore instance you create.

In order to for your 'submitScore' method to know about your variable, 'noSeconds', you're going to need to create it as an instance variable. (or you could just pass it along as a method argument)

So, in your .h:

```
double noSeconds;

@property (nonatomic, assign) double noSeconds;
```

then in your .m:

```
@synthesize noSeconds;

-(IBAction)gasPedalPressed:(id)sender {
    ...
    noSeconds = (double) [self.startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000;
    ...
}

-(IBAction)submitscore:(id)sender {
    ...
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"123"] autorelease];
    scoreReporter.value = noSeconds;
    ...
}
```

And it's always helpful to take a look at the applicable documentation: [GKScore Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks, but how would I implement that into my code? Sorry! im a complete beginner!

Comment: @RafeeSkull-manJenkins - Check my updated answer, hope it helps.

Comment: The score still won't submit! please could you email me so i can reply with my project do you can see what i have done wrong? Thank you kindly!